PnP JS - getShareLink is not working for PDF files
  const result: IShareLinkResponse = await sp.web
          .getFolderByServerRelativePath(documentUrl)
          .getShareLink(sharingLinkKind);

I am using this to generate shareable link with selected permission. But it is not working for PDF files as expected. For document files it is working fine.
Is there any API limitation with PnP SP for generating shareable link with pdf
